# Drools json Api call which contains Date (rule engine)

Tags: drools, rule-engine, fact

I am trying to call Drools Json api and one of my facts is of type Date. I am not sure how to construct the json string for that. !!!!????????? :(

here is what I have:

my drl file:
package com.beachmint.common

declare Order
        orderId: Integer
        customerId: Integer
        total: java.math.BigDecimal
        cartId: Integer
        createdAt: java.util.Date
        productIds: java.util.ArrayList
end

declare Customer
        customerId: Integer
        referrerId: Integer
        customerStatus: Integer
        createdAt: java.util.Date
end

declare Points
        status: String
        count: Integer
        customerId: Integer
        reason: String
        ruleId: String
end

declare Event
        name: String
        storeId: Integer
end

rule 'Purchase Promo'
dialect "mvel"
when
                e : Event( name matches "Purchase" )
                o : Order( total > 0 , createdAt > "08-Oct-2012" , createdAt <= "01-Jan-2013" )

then
                            p.setCount(  p.getCount() + 2000 );

I tried sending the date as UTC and string ('y-M-d) format.

createdAt":{"date":"2012-Jan-01"}
createdAt": 1351637683
createdAt": "2012-Jan-01"

none of these work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the default date format or, change it using drools.dateformat system property. See the [manual](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch04.html).

> 4.8.3.3.7.1. Date literal
>
> The date format dd-mmm-yyyy is supported by default. You can customize
>   this by providing an alternative date format mask as the System
>   property named drools.dateformat. If more control is required, use a
>   restriction.
>
> Example 4.36. Date Literal Restriction
>
> Cheese( bestBefore < "27-Oct-2009" )

Comment: yes I tried that but in the json request when I passed the date as a string ("27-Oct-2009") the rule engine fails since it's expecting a Date object. and I don't know how I can trick the drools to expect that as a Date object.  I am using JSON api in PHP

Comment: A workaround would be adding another String attribute to your objects that keeps the date in String format, and writing a conversion rule that fires when your date attribute is null and converts string value to date.